# How to access redux state in App.js (React-Native)

Tags: react-native, redux, react-redux

I am a beginner in react native and redux and working on it for the first time. I am not sure how to use the returned value in store.getState() in the App.js file.

```
console.ignoredYellowBox = ["Remote debugger"];
import { YellowBox } from "react-native";
YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
  "Unrecognized WebSocket connection option(s) `agent`, `perMessageDeflate`, `pfx`, `key`, `passphrase`, `cert`, `ca`, `ciphers`, `rejectUnauthorized`. Did you mean to put these under `headers`?",
]);
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, AsyncStorage } from "react-native";
import * as Font from "expo-font";
import { AppLoading } from "expo";
import AppNavigation from "./navigation/AppNavigator";
import { setNavigator } from "./navigationRef";
import userReducer from "./reducers/userReducer";
import chatReducer from "./reducers/chatReducer";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import { createStore, applyMiddleware, combineReducers } from "redux";
import ReduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';
import createSocketIoMiddleware from "redux-socket.io";
import io from "socket.io-client";

const store = createStore(combineReducers({userReducer, chatReducer}), applyMiddleware(ReduxThunk));
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    console.log(props);
    this.state = {
      fontLoaded: false,
    };
  }
  async componentWillMount(){
    const response = await(store.getState().userReducer.token)
    console.log("Response:", response)
  }
  render() {

    const fetchFont = () => {
      return Font.loadAsync({
        "raleway-bold": require("./assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf"),
        ralewayBold: require("./assets/fonts/Raleway-Bold.ttf"),
        "roboto-regular": require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"),
        robotoRegular: require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"),
        Roboto_medium: require("./assets/fonts/Roboto-Regular.ttf"),
      });
    };
    if (!this.state.fontLoaded) {
      return (
        <AppLoading
          startAsync={fetchFont}
          onFinish={() => this.setState({ fontLoaded: true })}
          onError={(err) => {
            console.log(err);
          }}
        />
      );
    }
    return (
      <Provider store={store}>
        <AppNavigation
          ref={(navigator) => {
            setNavigator(navigator);
          }}
        />
      </Provider>
    );
  }
}
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    backgroundColor: "#fff",
    alignItems: "center",
    justifyContent: "center",
  },
});

export default App;
```

**I want to get access to redux state from here to access the token stored there. After referring to few posts, I tried using store.getState() method but when I console.log it, I get null**

Answer (score 1):

You should not use directly the reference to `store`, instead you should use the method `connect` to connect your component, in this case `App` to the store as follows:

```
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
...
class App extends Component {
   constructor(props) {
     console.log(props.token);//you will get here the token
     ...
   }
   ...
}
....
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    token: state.userReducer.token,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {//You should put here your dispatch methods later
  };
};

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(App)
```

--------------- Edited -----------

I just noticed that you are trying to access the `store` inside the App component, but since you are defining the Provider in the `App.render` method you should do one of two things:
1) You should add the `<Provider store={store}>` one level above App. in the index.

```
<Provider store={store}>
 <App />
</Provider>
```

In this case, App render should not contain the Provider anymore.

2) You should move the logic of using the token to a level below of `App` and use the connect on the component below:

```
class IntermediateComponent extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
     console.log(props.token);//you will get here the token
     ...
  }
}
const mapStateToProps = (state) => {
  return {
    token: state.userReducer.token,
  };
};
const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {//You should put here your dispatch methods later
  };
};
const ConnectedIntermediateComponent = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(IntermediateComponent)

class App extends Component {
  ...
  render() {
    <Provider store={store}>
      <ConnectedIntermediateComponent>
        <AppNavigation
          ref={(navigator) => {
            setNavigator(navigator);
          }}
        />
      </ConnectedIntermediateComponent>
    </Provider>
  }
}

export default App;
```

Note that in 2) App is no longer connected.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but when i use connect inside my App.js file I get this error. "
Could not find "store" in the context of "Connect(App)". Either wrap the root component in a <Provider>, or pass a custom React context provider to <Provider> and the corresponding React context consumer to Connect(App) in connect options."

Comment: Thanks again. But I got access to redux state by just using store.getState().reducerName inside my constructor.

Answer (score 1):

**Brief Details**

example code of your **App.js** call

```
<Provider store={store}>
 <App />
</Provider>
```

Now we will try to **dispatch** and **getState** from the store without **connect** of **react-redux**

through this approach, we will not have the need of **mapStateToProps** and **mapDispatchToProps**

As we already *import* our *store* in **App.js**. e.g

```
import store from "./redux/store";
```

first, we dispatch some action from App.js through **store** directly.

like we have some action in our **epic** folder like this

```
import {someAction} from './redux/epics/fetch-some-epic'
```

Now this is our **dispatch** action from **App.js**

```
    store.dispatch(someAction())
```

and this is the **state** that we can get from **store** in our **App.js**

```
store.getState().someState
```

Thanks and regards